# How to revoke or invalidate token using Identity Server 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I read this docs: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/revocation.html

Then I try this code:

**AuthHelper.cs**

```
public class AuthHelper
{
    private string URL = "http://localhost:50847/connect/revocation";


    public bool revocarToken(string token)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string uri = URL;
            StringContent contenido = new StringContent("token="+token+"&token_type_hint=access_token", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(uri, contenido).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

But, I get this error:

[image]

I get an error 400 (Bad request). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You're not sending the required credentials to revocation end point. IdentityServer expects you to provide a client id and secret. Please read https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009#section-2.1 specification to understand better.

I recommend you to use [IdentityModel2](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2) package to make the revocation request (and other OIDC related requests).

Comment: I get similar error invalid_client for the revocation endpoint, but the introspection endpoint works fine, any ideas?